# Write query results from a table to a partitioned - clustered table in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have temp table where data is loaded from a cloud storage and a main table which is partitioned by **"tdate"** and clustered by "**serid**"

**tdate** and **serid** columns exists in temp table and tdate is like this format "YYYY-MM-DD" and serid is integer number

I know how to write query results like below.

```
CREATE TABLE `[project].[dataset].[dest table]`
PARTITION BY tdate
CLUSTER BY serid 
AS
SELECT * FROM `[project].[dataset].[table]`;
```

Can somebody tell me how can i achieve this to append data from temp table to main table  using **bq** command or in **python**

p:s Im new to gcp and just started today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use [script](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting)? I mean to run several queries in the same call separated by semicolon ;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `[project].[dataset].[dest table]` (
  # Add your schema here
  tdate date,
  serid numeric
)
  PARTITION BY tdate
  CLUSTER BY serid;
INSERT INTO `[project].[dataset].[dest table]` SELECT * FROM `[project].[dataset].[table]`;
```

Comment: so if i use insert script , i mean this "INSERT INTO `[project].[dataset].[dest table]` SELECT * FROM `[project].[dataset].[table]`;
" , this will take care of inserting data ryt .? and i might use to run several queries to write from temp table to multiple main tables

Comment: I didn't catch this `inserting data ryt .?`. And no problem for several queries in the same script, to write in one or several temp/dest tables. However, keep in mind that you pay for the data that you read in BigQuery. Choose smartly your query strategy to be the most cost efficient.

Comment: yea, that insert query you mentioned above, can i just run it ryt, i mean if i run that query, data from temp table will be inserted to dest table ryt ? coz my main table is partioned by tdate and clustered by serid  and ya, for the cost we are doing poc on gcp how much we can save if we migrate from  aws

Comment: Yes, it's an insert into the table, that Append the data. The first query create the table (the first time, if doesn't exist). It was your constraint. Anyway, BigQuery is simply magic! Especially for analytics.

Comment: Thanks a lot guillaume. yea, bigquery is awesome i never expected that it will be that much magic.but what i feel is lack of documentation, coz of that it might slow as well in getting started. such big products shd have clear and complete beginners to pro docs to hav good understanding

Comment: Don't hesitate to provide feedback on the documentation if you're happy with it. Or let me know your question. I could help you!

Comment: Wow, Your awesome Guillaume, Your words "i cloud help you "  is so big and Thanks a lot.I will get back to you if i need anything on gcp either on chat or here. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220087/discussion-between-chethan120-kumar-and-guillaume-blaquiere).